# specific string input exception handling

Tags: python, string, exception, input

I wrote this function to get user input of an integer and two strings (letters C F or K) for a temperature conversion exercise. I want to control the specificity of the input, i.e. that only the correct letters are entered and not another using the exception handling try: except: statements. The inputs are passed to the print function regardless, so even if you input say a “D”. I tried many things, but I am totally drawing a blank. Please help, need try: except to help me understand this in Python. Thanks. The code:

```
def gettemp ():
    while True:
        tempin = input ("Enter temperature value:")
        scalein = input ("Enter temperature scale (C/F/K):")
        scaleout = input ("Enter scale to convert to (C/F/K):")
        try:
            tempin == int (tempin)
            scalein == "C" or "F" or "K"
            scaleout == "C" or "F" or "K"
            return tempin, scalein, scaleout
        except NameError:
            print ("Please reenter:")
        
print (gettemp())
```

Comment: A conditional is a better fit than try/except here. Something like `if scalein in ('C', 'F', 'K') and scaleout in ('C', 'F', 'K'):`

Comment: try/expect will help to check if the input type is really what you want, for example when you got an input of `tempin` you will check the type if it's an int or raise a `ValueError`.
As @slothrop mentioned you should use conditons in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach using `or` is wrong. Using `or` on strings will return the first non-falsey string, in your case `scalein` and `scaleout` will both become `"C"`. Check if the scales are valid and raise an exception if they're not:

```py
def gettemp():
    while True:
        tempin = input("Enter temperature value:")
        scalein = input("Enter temperature scale (C/F/K):")
        scaleout = input("Enter scale to convert to (C/F/K):")
        try:
            tempin = int(tempin)  # also make sure to use the right equals
            valid = ("C", "F", "K")
            if scalein not in valid or scaleout not in valid:
                raise ValueError
            return tempin, scalein, scaleout
        except ValueError:
            print("Please reenter:")
        
print(gettemp())
```

You can also achieve this behavior without using a try-except block:

```py
def gettemp():
    while True:
        tempin = input("Enter temperature value:")
        scalein = input("Enter temperature scale (C/F/K):")
        scaleout = input("Enter scale to convert to (C/F/K):")
        valid = ("C", "F", "K")
        if not tempin.isnumeric() or scalein not in valid or scaleout not in valid:
            print("Please reenter:")
            continue
        return int(tempin), scalein, scaleout
        
print(gettemp())
```

Comment: Thanks all! @B Remmelzwaal the code changes now indeed raise a ValueError when inappropriate strings are entered, but I want to use the try: error; exception handling to prompt a reenter and prevent the program form crashing.

Comment: Is it not better style to assign a set to *valid* rather than a tuple? Or perhaps just "CFK"

Comment: I fixed it, Thanks! Just need to change the condition and remove the raise Value Error

Comment: That's exactly what should happen with the code I've provided. You don't even need a try-except block to do input validation like this.

Comment: @Dr.H are you still using `except NameError` in your code? With this approach it should be `except ValueError`

Comment: @slothrop I changed it to ValueError, now it gets interesting. In the first case if a non integer is entered, for tempin the code flows to the except and prints "Please reenter" and asks for new input. In the other two cases (i.e. invalid string inpit) it doesn't flow to the except but direclty asks for reinput. I assume this is because of the True in the while loop. Any ideas how to continue to the except also in these two cases:

Comment: The `raise ValueError` in the original answer should do exactly that.

Comment: Behind the if: statement that causes it to crash

Comment: Is possible to add it in the except?

Comment: I can't replicate that crash. Are you using the exact code of the original answer, or have you modified it?

Comment: Sorry, exact answer works fine. I will figure it out. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are testing whether `scalein` equals "C" is true or "F" is true or "K" is true. Since "F" and "K" are truthy, [see](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/)

the condition will always be true.

Change your criteria to

```
scalein == "C" or scalein == "F" or scalein == "K"
scaleout == "C" or scaleout == "F" or scaleout == "K"
```

or even

```
scalein in ('C', 'F', 'K')
```

But this will not yet solve your problem. You need to check whether both `scalein` and `scaleout` are of the values you expect and `return` only if they are, that is, raise an error if your criteria is false.